# What happens when two players both play Control Magic on the same creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, I control a [Pathraizer of Ulamog](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pathraizer%20of%20Ulamog). One of my opponents cast [Control Magic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Control%20Magic) on it to take control of it. Then my other opponent casts the same spell. How can they both control it?

Comment: I think that an older question, [*Perplexing Chimera + Hypnotic Siren. Do I control all of my opponent's spells?*](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/15347/6692), should be closed as a duplicate of this newer question. This one is worded so much better.

Comment: Even if this question were asked first, I would still leave that question open to handle the interaction between different types of control change effects (aura vs unattached continuous effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last effect created takes precedence.

Section 613 resolves interaction of Continuous Effects. The rules relevant to this specific question are the following:

> 613.6. Within a layer or sublayer, determining which order effects are applied in is usually done using a timestamp system. An effect with an earlier timestamp is applied before an effect with a later timestamp.
>
> 613.6a A continuous effect generated by a static ability has the same timestamp as the object the static ability is on, or the timestamp of the effect that created the ability, whichever is later.

Continuous effects are continually reevaluated. This means that destroying the second Control Magic gives control of Pathraizer to the controller of the first Control Magic.